# Older PHP versions missing from Microsoft-hosted Azure agents

Tags: php, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to migrate a project that was initially running on a self-hosted agent to a Microsoft-hosted agent on Azure DevOps.
I'm running into a problem where I can't seem to specify the PHP version that I need. The project is using PHP7.2 that I know isn't supported and recommended anymore, but it's not in the scope right now to do the upgrade.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/php?view=azure-devops) states the way of changing the version to 7.2, but it's probably not up-to-date because `ubuntu-latest` and `ubuntu-20.04` don't have versions older than 7.4 installed anymore.

Is there a way to install and setup the older PHP version? Is my only option to install it to the agent on every run from some repository like ondrej?

I tried to change the vmImage to `ubuntu-16.04` and `ubuntu-18.04` but they don't exist anymore.

Comment: You should have done the upgrade years ago. PHP 7.2 is out of support since more than two years. See https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md  for more details

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but have you tested the application on PHP 8? Depending on how the application is written, it might not be that much to patch? Just so you don't spend more time researching and trying to install an out-of-date version of PHP than it would take to update the code.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I didn't. The project is a big one and we don't have tests to cover everything in it. Unfortunately there are no resources to test everything manually. I understand what you're saying but it would still be faster to somehow run the correct PHP version. Thanks!

Comment: "Is my only option to install ... some repository like ondre" - I think the answer is yes. To alleviate any concerns, I wouldn't consider "ondrej" to be just "some repository". From [their site](https://deb.sury.org/): "...the official packages in Debian and Ubuntu are either my work or they are based on my work. The PHP packages in my Ubuntu PPA and Debian DPA matches the official packages in Debian. Basically I am saying that you can’t get any closer than that."

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes of course, I know that his repo is pretty much the official one. I did implement it this way and it works fine. It does come with a cost of having to run download/install/setup PHP version on every run (and in every job).

Answer (score -2):

Their [documentation on Github](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md) helps figuring this out:

> Once a version of PHP has reached it's end of extended support your application will be upgraded to the next recommended supported minor version.

This date was Feb 01st 2021 for PHP 7.2.

Side notice: You should have done the upgrade years ago. PHP 7.2 itself is out of support since Dec 2020. Even an upgrade to PHP 7.4 (which could be simpler than upgrading to PHP 8 directly) doesn't help you out, as this is out of support since the end of 2022.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about how agents upgrade their versions. I do know how projects should be updated when versions come to their end, but this is not the case in real-life projects. I'm familiar with how things should work, but for these cases I asked this question because this is currently the only option. Thanks